# antlr creating a child node from three different possible options

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3

Couldn't really find an answer to this. Note: using antlr 3 not 4 if that matters. 
Trying to construct a child node based on three different possible expressions.

```
 (variable)* (n_expr|d_expr|s_expr)+
            {

            } -> ^(FORMULA_DEF n_expr|d_expr|s_expr)
```

Throws an error because I can't use (n_expr|d_expr|s_expr) for the children node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them all to a common list of subtrees:

```
(variable)* (e+=num_expr|e+=date_expr|e+=string_expr)+
-> ^(FORMULA_DEF INTEGER RCALL $e+)
```

or if you want a new `FORMULA_DEF` for each expr

```
(variable)* (e+=num_expr|e+=date_expr|e+=string_expr)+
-> ^(FORMULA_DEF INTEGER RCALL $e)+
```

Comment: what is e defined as?

Comment: `e` is an ANTLR variable, ANTLR should define it as a list of tree nodes in the generated code. No need to define it explicitly in grammar

Comment: The (e+= ...|e+= ...| e+=.. ) works fine. But by doing ^(FORMULA_DEF INTEGER RCALL e+) I get a reference to undefined rule: e.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Forgot the dollar signs.